# Unshelve to a different branch using Visual Studio Online

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

Is it possible to unshelve to a different branch using the new [Visual Studio Online](https://blog.discountasp.net/team-foundation-server-vs-visual-studio-online/) TFS repository? I've tried using TFS Power Tools 2015 and the following command:

```
tfpt unshelve /migrate /source:"$/Sportlabs.Sportbench/Development/Sportlabs.Sportbench" /target:"$/Sportlabs.Sportbench/Development6/Sportlabs.Sportbench" "SR-Coaching"
```

I ran this from `C:\Code\TFS\Sportlabs.Sportbench`, which is mapped to `$/Sportlabs.Sportbench` in my local workspace. I've tried using both the Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 Developer command prompts. However, I keep getting the `unable to determine the workspace` error.

I've read that MS have abandoned power tools in TFS 2017 and built most of them in to TFS. If that's also the case for VS Online, how do I go about unshelving into a different branch?

Comment: Did you try to run `tf workspaces` to refresh the Workspace cache? If you run `tf workspace` does it open the Workspace window?

Comment: Yes, running `tf workspace` opens the workspace window. I tried running `tf workspaces` and then `tfpt unshelve`, but I still get the error

Comment: Try to run the command from C:\Code\TFS\Sportlabs.Sportbench\Development\Sportlabs.Sportbench and check the result. On the other hand, try to get the latest version and run that command. http://benjii.me/2014/04/move-shelveset-to-different-branch-in-tfs/

Comment: It is working fine for me with VS 2015 developer command and VS Online (VSTS)

Answer (score 3):

To identify the current Workspace, tfpt seems to use the Method:

```
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.Workstation.Current.GetLocalWorkspaceInfo(workspacePath)
```

I've jsut tried with TFS 2015 API and the call returns no result againt a Workspace of a VSTS project. I've also try with the TFS 2017 API and it works.

I don't think it will ever be possible to use TFPT 2015 againt a VSTS project to do TFVC operations.

Comment: What a pain - thanks @Gregory_Ott - adds fuel to my "we should start using Git" argument :)

Comment: Its a pain because they didnt open source it and havent bothered to fix it.